# Как создать кастомный Dialog?

Tags: android

Я создаю `Dialog` пишу `setContentenView` указываю `Layout`. И я получаю диалог с `Actionbar`. Как сделать так чтобы `Dialog` был без `Actionbar` и по середине?

```
final Dialog dialog=new Dialog(Eda2.this,R.style.Eda2Diag);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.eda2_diag);
                dialog.show();
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Eda2Diag" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: А вы свой диалог от чего наследуете? Надо бы от DialogFragment. А в каком диалоге вы setContenView нашли я даже не представляю.

Comment: Вон скинул код, вот так сделал. но фигня какая то получается. какие то рамки вокруг диалога.

Я просто хочу чтобы layout появился поверх окна и чтобы он был по середине, а задний план был серый

Comment: А стиль R.style.Eda2Diag вы случаем не от стиля какойнить активити с экшн баром унаследовали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед `dialog.setContentView(R.layout.eda2_diag);` попробуйте добавить

**для центрирования:**

```
Window window = dialog.getWindow();
window.setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
window.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

**убрать заголовок диалога:**

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```